# Difference in Elm between type and type alias?

Tags: elm

In Elm, I can't figure out when `type` is the appropriate keyword vs. `type alias`. The documentation doesn't seem to have an explanation of this, nor can I find one in the release notes. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

How I think of it:

`type` is used for defining new union types:

```elm
type Thing = Something | SomethingElse
```

Before this definition `Something` and `SomethingElse` didn't mean anything. Now they are both of type `Thing`, which we just defined.

`type alias` is used for giving a name to some other type that already exists:

```elm
type alias Location = { lat:Int, long:Int }
```

`{ lat = 5, long = 10 }` has type `{ lat:Int, long:Int }`, which was already a valid type. But now we can also say it has type `Location` because that is an alias for the same type.

It is worth noting that the following will compile just fine and display `"thing"`. Even though we specify `thing` is a `String` and `aliasedStringIdentity` takes an `AliasedString`, we won't get an error that there is a type mismatch between `String`/`AliasedString`:

```elm
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)

type alias AliasedString = String

aliasedStringIdentity: AliasedString -> AliasedString
aliasedStringIdentity s = s

thing : String
thing = "thing"

main =
  show <| aliasedStringIdentity thing
```

Comment: Not sure about your point of last paragraph. Are you trying to say they are still the same type no matter how you alias it?

Comment: Yes, just pointing out that the compiler considers the aliased type to be the same as the original

Comment: So when you use the `{}` record syntax, you're defining a new type?

Comment: `{ lat:Int, long:Int }` doesn't define a new type. That's a valid type already. `type alias Location = { lat:Int, long:Int }` also doesn't define a new type, it just gives another (perhaps more descriptive) name to an already valid type. `type Location = Geo { lat:Int, long:Int }` would define a new type (`Location`)

Comment: When should one use type vs. type alias? Where is the downside of always using type?

Comment: For more info, see [the official Elm community faq about type vs. type alias](http://faq.elm-community.org/#what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-type-alias)

Comment: Regarding when to use type vs. type alias: I collected a couple of examples in my answer below. The topic of types is pretty deep though, so if you are looking for more, probably R.Feldman's advanced Elm course is a great resource: https://frontendmasters.com/courses/advanced-elm/

Answer (score 11):

The key is the word `alias`. In the course of programming, when you want to group things that belong together, you put it in a record, like in the case of a point

```
{ x = 5, y = 4 }
```

or a student record.

```
{ name = "Billy Bob", grade = 10, classof = 1998 }
```

Now, if you needed to pass these records around, you'd have to spell out the entire type, like:

```
add : { x:Int, y:Int } -> { x:Int, y:Int } -> { x:Int, y:Int }
add a b =
  { a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y }
```

If you could alias a point, the signature would be so much easier to write!

```
type alias Point = { x:Int, y:Int }
add : Point -> Point -> Point
add a b =
  { a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y }
```

So an alias is a shorthand for something else. Here, it's a shorthand for a record type. You can think of it as giving a name to a record type you'll be using often. That's why it's called an alias--it's another name for the naked record type that's represented by `{ x:Int, y:Int }`

Whereas `type` solves a different problem. If you're coming from OOP, it's the problem you solve with inheritance, operator overloading, etc.--sometimes, you want to treat the data as a generic thing, and sometimes you want to treat it like a specific thing.

A commonplace where this happens is when passing around messages--like the postal system. When you send a letter, you want the postal system to treat all messages as the same thing, so you only have to design the postal system once. And besides, the job of routing the message should be independent of the message contained within. It's only when the letter reaches its destination do you care about what the message is.

In the same way, we might define a `type` as a union of all the different types of messages that could happen. Say we're implementing a messaging system between college students to their parents. So there are only two messages college kids can send: 'I need beer money' and 'I need underpants'.

```
type MessageHome = NeedBeerMoney | NeedUnderpants
```

So now, when we design the routing system, the types for our functions can just pass around `MessageHome`, instead of worrying about all the different types of messages it could be. The routing system doesn't care. It only needs to know it's a `MessageHome`. It's only when the message reaches its destination, the parent's home, that you need to figure out what it is.

```
case message of
  NeedBeerMoney ->
    sayNo()
  NeedUnderpants ->
    sendUnderpants(3)
```

If you know the Elm architecture, the update function is a giant case statement, because that's the destination of where the message gets routed, and hence processed. And we use union types to have a single type to deal with when passing the message around, but then can use a case statement to tease out exactly what message it was, so we can deal with it.

Answer (score 8):

*Let me complement the previous answers by focusing on use-cases and providing a little context on constructor functions and modules.*

---

### Usages of `type alias`

1. **Create an alias and a constructor function for a record**
   This the most common use-case: you can define an alternate name and constructor function for a particular kind of record format.

   ```
   type alias Person =
       { name : String
       , age : Int
       }
   ```

   Defining the type alias automatically implies the following constructor function (pseudo code):
   `Person : String -> Int -> { name : String, age : Int }`
   This can come handy, for instance when you want to write a Json decoder.

   ```
   personDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Person
   personDecoder =
       Json.Decode.map2 Person
           (Json.Decode.field "name" Json.Decode.String)
           (Json.Decode.field "age" Int)
   ```
2. **Specify required fields**
   They sometimes call it "extensible records", which can be misleading.
   This syntax can be used to specify that you are expecting some record with particular fields present. Such as:

   ```
   type alias NamedThing x =
       { x
           | name : String
       }

   showName : NamedThing x -> Html msg
   showName thing =
       Html.text thing.name
   ```

   Then you can use the above function like this (for example in your view):

   ```
   let
       joe = { name = "Joe", age = 34 }
   in
       showName joe
   ```

   [Richard Feldman's talk on ElmEurope 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoA4Txr4GUs) may provide some further insight into when this style is worth using.
3. **Renaming stuff**
   You might do this, because the new names could provide extra meaning
   later on in your code, like in this example

   ```elm
   type alias Id = String

   type alias ElapsedTime = Time

   type SessionStatus
       = NotStarted
       | Active Id ElapsedTime
       | Finished Id
   ```

   Perhaps a better example of [this kind of usage in core is `Time`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Time).
4. **Re-exposing a type from a different module**
   If you are writing a package (not an application), you may need to implement a type in one module, perhaps in an internal (not exposed) module, but you want to expose the type from a different (public) module. Or, alternatively, you want to expose your type from multiple modules.
   [`Task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Task#Task) in core and [Http.Request in Http](https://github.com/elm-lang/http/blob/1.0.0/src/Http.elm#L58) are examples for the first, while the [Json.Encode.Value](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Encode#Value) and [Json.Decode.Value](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#Value) pair is an example of the later.

   You can only do this when you otherwise want to keep the type opaque: you don't expose the constructor functions. For details see usages of `type` below.

It is worth noticing that in the above examples only #1 provides a constructor function. If you expose your type alias in #1 like `module Data exposing (Person)` that will expose the type name as well as the constructor function.

### Usages of `type`

1. **Define a tagged union type**
   This is the most common use-case, a good example of it is the [`Maybe` type in core](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/5.1.1/src/Maybe.elm):

   ```
   type Maybe a
       = Just a
       | Nothing
   ```

   When you define a type, you also define its constructor functions. In case of Maybe these are (pseudo-code):

   ```
   Just : a -> Maybe a

   Nothing : Maybe a
   ```

   Which means that if you declare this value:

   ```
   mayHaveANumber : Maybe Int
   ```

   You can create it by either

   ```
   mayHaveANumber = Nothing
   ```

   or

   ```
   mayHaveANumber = Just 5
   ```

   The `Just` and `Nothing` tags not only serve as constructor functions, they also serve as destructors or patterns in a `case` expression. Which means that using these patterns you can see inside a `Maybe`:

   ```
   showValue : Maybe Int -> Html msg
   showValue mayHaveANumber =
       case mayHaveANumber of
           Nothing ->
               Html.text "N/A"

           Just number ->
               Html.text (toString number)
   ```

   You can do this, because the Maybe module is defined like

   ```
   module Maybe exposing 
       ( Maybe(Just,Nothing)
   ```

   It could also say

   ```
   module Maybe exposing 
       ( Maybe(..)
   ```

   The two are equivalent in this case, but being explicit is considered a virtue in Elm, especially when you are writing a package.

2. **Hiding implementation details**
   As pointed out above it is a deliberate choice that the constructor functions of `Maybe` are visible for other modules.

   There are other cases, however, when the author decides to hide them. [One example of this in core is `Dict`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Dict). As the consumer of the package, you should not be able to see the implementation details of the Red/Black tree algorithm behind `Dict` and mess with the nodes directly. Hiding the constructor functions forces the consumer of your module/package to only create values of your type (and then transform those values) through the functions you expose.

   This is the reason why sometimes stuff like this appears in code

   ```
   type Person =
       Person { name : String, age : Int }
   ```

   Unlike the `type alias` definition at the top of this post, this syntax creates a new "union" type with only one constructor function, but that constructor function can be hidden from other modules/packages.

   If the type is exposed like this:

   ```
   module Data exposing (Person)
   ```

   Only code in the `Data` module can create a Person value and only that code can pattern match on it.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference, as I see it, is whether type checker will yell on you if you use "synomical" type.

Create the following file, put it somewhere and run `elm-reactor`, then go to `http://localhost:8000` to see the difference:

```elm
-- Boilerplate code

module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (..)

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    {
      model = identity,
      view = view,
      update = identity
    }

-- Our type system

type alias IntRecordAlias = {x : Int}
type IntRecordType =
  IntRecordType {x : Int}

inc : {x : Int} -> {x : Int}
inc r = {r | x = .x r + 1}

view model =
  let
    -- 1. This will work
    r : IntRecordAlias
    r = {x = 1}

    -- 2. However, this won't work
    -- r : IntRecordType
    -- r = IntRecordType {x = 1}
  in
    Html.text <| toString <| inc r
```

If you uncomment `2.` and comment `1.` you will see:

```
The argument to function `inc` is causing a mismatch.

34|                              inc r
                                     ^
Function `inc` is expecting the argument to be:

    { x : Int }

But it is:

    IntRecordType
```

Answer (score 0):

An `alias` is just a shorter name for some other type, similar `class` in OOP. Exp:

```
type alias Point =
  { x : Int
  , y : Int
  }
```

An `type` (without alias) will let you define your own type, so you can define types like `Int`, `String`,... for you app. For exmaple, in common case, it can use for description of a state of app:

```
type AppState = 
  Loading          --loading state
  |Loaded          --load successful
  |Error String    --Loading error
```

So you you can easy to handle it in `view` elm:

```
-- VIEW
...
case appState of
    Loading -> showSpinner
    Loaded -> showSuccessData
    Error error -> showError

...
```

I think you know the difference between `type` and `type alias`.

But why and how to use `type` and `type alias` is important with `elm` app, you guys can refer the [article from Josh Clayton](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/lessons-learned-avoiding-primitives-in-elm)